# Verified account CAN NOT add developer app

Tags: facebook, installation

I've combed the internet looking for a solution and I have none.

For some reason, my page can't add the facebook developer app. I don't get the box that pops up asking to to allow even. When I click "go to app" it takes me back to my page. It IS verified, I've tried logging into the developer page and going from there and nothing works. I checked the "apps" section on my page and it says I haven't authorized anything even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have always use HTTPS enabled on your profile, however in your app settings, you don't have a valid HTTPS url listed.

Instead of logging in as the page, log in as a page admin (normal facebook user) and try adding the app.

Comment: No, I have HTTPS disabled, and no options for that in my app settings.

Comment: Sure you have an option in your app settings for https.  It's a new requirement for Facebook apps as of Oct 2011.  It had better be there!

Comment: I can't even get that far because when I try to add the developer app, it re-directs me to my page.

Comment: Instead of logging in as the page, log in as a page admin (normal facebook user) and try adding the app.

Comment: Hello.

I have the same issue but I do not have any other login besides the company page.

Do I need to create another profile or how do I work around this?

Thank you.

Comment: You should start your own question.  As this one marked as the accepted answer for the question asked.